# AngularJS $http get request неверно кодирует объект, в котором содержится дата

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Всем привет!

Когда я пытаюсь отправить объект (объект содержит дату, как свойство) через модуль $http (тип GET) - То в URL я получаю ":".

Например объект

```
var a = {date:"15:36", name:"Test"}
```

Я ожидаю, что получу URL типа:
"site.com?date=15%3A36&name=test"

Но по факту получаю:
"site.com?date=15:36&name=test"

Если я правильно понял - причина здесь:
github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js

Line 50:

```
parts.push(encodeUriQuery(key) + '=' + encodeUriQuery(serializeValue(value)));
```

В моем примере это объект, а не массив.
Сначала происходит сериализация. (serializeValue(value))

Line 13-18

```
function serializeValue(v) {
  if (isObject(v)) {
    return isDate(v) ? v.toISOString() : toJson(v);
  }
  return v;
}
```

Это объект, но не дата (он содержит дату, как свойство). Поэтому получаем JSON-строку.

После этого происходит кодирование.

Я нашел его здесь:
github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/720012eab6fef5e075a1d6876dd2e508c8e95b73/src/ngResource/resource.js

(Lines 405-411) (не смог добавить 2 ссылки, не хватило репутации, простите)

```
  function encodeUriQuery(val, pctEncodeSpaces) {
    return encodeURIComponent(val).
      replace(/%40/gi, '@').
      replace(/%3A/gi, ':').
      replace(/%24/g, '$').
      replace(/%2C/gi, ',').
      replace(/%20/g, (pctEncodeSpaces ? '%20' : '+'));
  }
```

В начале оно использует encodeURIComponent, но затем возвращает назад значения: "@",":","$",",".

Это баг AngularJS'a, или я делаю что-то неверно?

Я использую AngularJS версии 1.5.6

Заранее большое спасибо.
С уважением, Артем.

PS Перепутал русский Stackoverflow с английским, поэтому вначале запостил сюда всё на английском. Перевел. Я задал аналогичный вопрос на английском stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44713104/angularjs-http-get-request-is-not-correctly-encoding-dates-inside-object

```
config = Object.assign({
      method: "GET",
      url: targetUrl,
      data: null,
      params: getDataObject,
      timeout: 50000,
    }, config);
return $http(config)
```

Comment: Двоеточие ведь допустимый символ, почему оно вдруг должно экранироваться?

Comment: И приведите код отправки данных.

Comment: Насчет допустимости символов - мне кажется не зря ведь encodeUriComponent все подобные символы кодирует? encodeURIComponent("1!2@3#4$5%6^7&8*9(0)-_=+:;'") выводит "1!2%403%234%245%256%5E7%268*9(0)-_%3D%2B%3A%3B'". Пример кода я смогу привести чуть попозже, сейчас возможности нет.

Answer (score 0):

В AngularJS версии 1.5.4 уже как то не комильфо использовать $http. Попробуйте всё таки воспользоваться сервисом `$resource`. 
Вот вам пример отправки данных через `$resource`:

```
var User = $resource('/user');
User.post({userId:123, name: 'Иванов Иван'});
```

[Документация](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Comment: К сожалению приходится пользоваться $http, так как это существующий проект. Хотелось бы решить проблему без изменений зависимостей и существующей структуры.

Comment: Приведите тогда структуру вашего процесса отправки. Сервис ``$resource`` это надстройка над ``$http``. Данные, аналогичные вашим (время в формате yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss), в нашем проекте гоняются ежеминутно и никаких проблем это не вызывает.